# JQuery basics - Selecting elements inside a cached element

Tags: jquery, caching, css-selectors

Sorry but this is a really basic jQuery syntax question, but I can't find anyone discussing it anywhere (probably as I don't know the correct terms to search for).

I want to select/cache a  using a variable and then later get the value of checked inputs within that .
Now I know I could do this without caching as:

```
var questionID = (a string)
$(questionID + " input:radio:checked").val()
```

But I use the div#'questionID' object a number of times so want to cache it i.e.

```
questionID = '#' + ...Something that changes ...
$question = $(questionID);
```

Now that $question is a jQuery object I can't work out how to select things inside it (without using children())

For example the following don't work:

```
$question.(' input:radio:checked)
$($question 'input:radio:checked')
```

I imagine this is a really basic bit of syntax, but I can't find it anywhere and I've tried lots of combinations with no luck......

Any help would be highly appreciated and apologies if this is really dumb but I'm very new to jQuery,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var checkedRadios = $('input:radio:checked', $question);
```

OR

```
var checkedRadios = $question.find('input:radio:checked');
```

This is called tree traversing, you can find more about tree traversing api in [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

The [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method is used to search for elements under a given scope.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm looking for. I'd looked at moving around the DOM, but must have missed the $.find().

Comment: For the first method, I thought that this selector selects multiple elements (i.e. it selects any 'input:radio:checked' and '$question') rather than selecting them in a hierarchical way (i.e. $('a',$b) selecting a under $b.)

Answer (score 0):

Use .find(), I think thats what your looking for!

```
$question.find('input:radio:checked');
```

**EDIT** I suggest skimming through jQuery API, http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('input:radio:checked', $question)`...

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for

```
var checkedRadiosInsideQuestion = $question.find('input:radio:checked');
```